# Sword of Truth 4e Setting

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-development, campaign-settings, intellectual-property

Has anyone seen or heard of anyone working up a [Sword of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_of_Truth) series 4e setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an official RPG setting for [The Sword of Truth](http://www.terrygoodkind.com/forum/archive/index.php?f-4.html). Terry Goodkind will not license the book for an RPG. From the official [Sword of Truth FAQ](http://www.terrygoodkind.com/forum/archive/index.php?t-17.html):

> QUESTION 4 Are there any SOT RPGs or
>   video games or D&D type games out
>   there?
>
> ANSWER 4 No, there is not. Terry is
>   adamantly against having his books
>   made into a video game because he sees
>   them as a medium that is incapable of
>   incorporating his philosophy and story
>   elements into the game, which he sees
>   as the most important parts. So he
>   doesn't want to have a game made when
>   it will just contain the fantasy
>   elements as well as changes to the
>   story, which there would have to be to
>   make the game viable. The same thing
>   applies to the D&D type game. We may
>   disagree with him and might not like
>   it, but 'dems the breaks.

You might adapt [the work others have done](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=128280) creating a Sword of Truth setting for D&D 3rd Edition.

Comment: That sucks massive amounts... Thanks for the indie work.

Comment: @Adam: For what it's worth, you've got linkrot on your Sword of Truth forum links.  Not sure if these have been reposted elsewhere, since I don't see anything obvious.  I could guess, but you might have a better idea about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No

It would be challenging to do moreso because of the relative rarity of magic, the naturalist tones (the difference between men and women's han for example), the rather absolute nature of some of the magics (do you see a confessor's touch being Save ends) and the difference in power level between say richard and more or less anyone else.

and just to comment on the above, after watching the tv version, I have a hard time believing philosophy has much to do with it.